# Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4

I decided to convert my DAL to Entity Framework 4.0.
I already have my huge database and also many business classes.
How can I map the tables and fields to my classes?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to skin this cat.  [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) is one that comes to mind.

You can also do it manually with LINQ, for example:

```
MyObject obj = (from e in entityModel
                select new MyObject {
                  ID = e.ID, 
                  Name = e.Name, 
                  // etc...
                }
               );
```

You can also write your own method that uses Reflection to map properties by type and name.

...Just throwing a bunch of ideas out there.

Comment: @Kon: I am sorry but I am new to EF. Is it common that people convert the entity objects to their own business objects? is this the way we should use the EF?

Comment: I've seen it done and have done it different ways.  In fact, I've done all 3 methods that I mentioned, and I've also used the EF-generated models directly in the front-end (which is the simplest way to do it, especially for relatively small projects/web pages).  There are pros and cons to all.  AutoMapper is nice because it makes mapping relatively painless.  However, as with most third-party libraries, there's probably some overhead there (which may or may not be okay with you on this proj).  LINQ mapping is nice because there's little overhead, but you still have to...

Comment: ...map each property youself, and keep that logic updated whenever your DB schema changes.  Mapping using Reflection is more complicated to implement initially, but you hardly have to update it after that, even when DB schema changes.  But you pay a price - using Reflection, which (again) may or may not be okay with you for this particular proj.  

Either way, I recommend more research via Google to see what fits your needs best.

Comment: @Kon: Thanks for the detaild answer! In order to use those methds the DAL library project should know the BLL library project. Am I right?

Comment: The Automapper is particular useful when used with the ASP.NET MVC framework for mapping between models and entity classes.

Comment: @Nick, unless you make your model the entity class itself - cut out the middle man.

Comment: @Naor, yes, that's how I'd do it.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework allows you to create a mapping for your "conceptual" domain (your objects), and a separate mapping for the "storage" domain (your database).  You then map these together using a central conceptual<->storage mapping specification.  It sounds complicated, and unfortunately it is...  EF is not a lightweight tool.

There's a lot to learn, but a place to start would be to read up on the [CSDL, SSDL, and MSL specifications for Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399604.aspx).

If you want to use your current objects and database, you may have to define custom mappings in CSDL, SSDL, and MSL.  If you want to make your life easier, you could generate a default Entity Data Model using the built-in Visual Studio tools.  Creating an EDM from an existing database will generate objects that map to your database, but there are about a million ways to customize this process, and there are several ways to define your objects so that they can be used with EF.

I would suggest creating a default EDM from your database, and take a look at the .edmx file that is produced.  An .edmx usually contains the CSDL, SSDL, and MSL in an XML format, along with generated code.  (Again this can be totally customized).  You might want to also spend some time reading up on [EF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx)... it's a beast.

Comment: What is the difference between Kon's answer and defining the CSDL, SSDL, and MSL myself? Which is the better in terms of efficiency?

Comment: Kon is talking about querying your database, and manually or automatically mapping the resulting objects into your existing object model.  You could do something like this if you opted to generate a default EDM using the EF tools, and then map these default generated objects into your objects.  I can't really say what the best approach is for your case, I would suggest just sticking to the basics at first, and as you learn more, explore other ways of doing things.

Comment: So by defining the CSDL, SSDL, and MSL myself I actually create "my own" EDM?